# MTP not working after Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, android, mtp

I could connect to my Android Alcatel Pixi 4 (5) via MTP on Ubuntu 16.04 (there was a bug where the protocol "died unexpectedly" if a file delete was followed by a file copy, but other than that, it worked).

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 I get "protocol died unexpectedly" in Dolphin whenever I try to browse the device.

```
#> mtp-detect
libmtp version: 1.1.13

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=1bbb and PID=0167) is a Alcatel/TCT 6010D/TCL S950.
   Found 1 device(s):
   Alcatel/TCT: 6010D/TCL S950 (1bbb:0167) @ bus 3, dev 2
Attempting to connect device(s)
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

dmesg contains:

```
[  471.588800] usb 3-4: usbfs: process 9290 (gmtp) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  471.715547] usb 3-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  471.864513] usb 3-4: usbfs: process 9290 (gmtp) did not claim interface 0 before use
[  471.864735] usb 3-4: usbfs: process 2562 (events) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

I tried building libmtp-1.1.15 from source, problem persists. The device works via MTP access on Windows on the same machine.

Comment: Try KDE Connect on both ends, Ubuntu and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en).

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue with my openSUSE.  After I have installed `jmtpfs`, `kio-mtp` `mtp-tools` the issue disappeared and everything started to work correctly.

If you have already used `jmtpfs` or a similar tool with a mount point of `~/android_mount/`, then first make sure it's not mounted:

```
# unmount previously mounted device
fusermount -u ~/android_mount/

# this should show empty directory
ls -la ~/android_mount/
```

You can also use the output of `df` to see if perhaps it's mounted elsewhere.

Otherwise, create a new mount point, let's say `~/android_mount/` and mount your Android phone, after you connected it with USB cable and switched it to 'File Transfer' mode (it normally defaults to 'Charge'):

```
# make directory to mount
mkdir -p ~/android_mount/

# mount the device (can take several minutes)
# it will also show device information while mounting
jmtpfs ~/android_mount/

# now you should see internal storage if you don't have an SD card
ls -la ~/android_mount/
drwxrwxr-x 12 login login    0 Jan  3  44248648 Internal storage
# if it has an SD card too, then it'll show 2 entries

# look inside
ls -la ~/android_mount/Internal\ storage/
```

Now you can operate on the files as you'd on any USB attached device.

```
# when finished, unmount the device
fusermount -u ~/android_mount/
```

Could you add `jmtpfs -l` to your question?

Comment: 1. Your first 2 commands make no sense to someone who doesn't already have your specific dir names, which aren't standard. 2. and the last one should probably have a comment that you're unmounting it? 3. plus can you replace `/home/login` with `~` to be consistent with the rest of your steps? Thank you.
The complete instructions with debug options can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/mtp).

Comment: @StasBekman those were the commands I used - could not copy, but had to rewrite them.  You were right about the one directory, which I edited (feel free to edit it next time).  There are plenty of guides (the debian one is better one but the OP has Ubuntu which could differ). I wrote I used different linux distro.  As for the guides you could also link an Arch linux one - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Media_Transfer_Protocol.

Comment: sure, I edited it as you suggested. Please feel free to further improve it. In this case the distro doesn't matter at all - since it's the same tool. Thank you for your sharing.

Comment: It seems that installing jmtpfs does the magic. A question is WHY an upgrade to ubuntu can KILL such important and basic function...

Answer (score 0):

If MTP does not work, you may try instead KDE Connect.

See these references :

- [How to Install KDE Connect in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-kde-connect-ubuntu-16-04)
- [KDE Connect on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en)

Comment: Downvoter: MTP sometimes simply does not work under certain conditions, so an alternative might be required.

Comment: When Linux don't work for you use Windows

Answer (score 0):

make directory to mount

```
mkdir -p ~/android_mount/
```

mount the device (can take several minutes)
it will also show device information while mounting

```
jmtpfs ~/android_mount/
```

now you should see internal storage if you don't have an SD card

```
ls -la ~/android_mount/

drwxrwxr-x 12 login login    0 Jan  3  44248648 Internal storage
```

if it has an SD card too, then it'll show 2 entries

look inside

```
ls -la ~/android_mount/Internal\ storage/
```

My mobile starts working now ...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the gvfs, mtp* packages, in Synaptic, and under package->force package version you should have it set to (codename)-updates. If it fails remove package and reinstall all packages you remove. The packages probably didn't get upgraded to the appropriate version.

Reboot and you should see Android devices open.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 Galaxy (one Note4 and one S8), and curiously that issue was only appear with my S8.
I managed to fix it by installing go-mtpfs gvfs-fuse and mainly **limesuite-udev**